# Join list of strings with a comma

Tags: abap

I am learning ABAP. In the past I used python.

```
Python: ', '.join(['one', 'two', 'three'])
Result: 'one, two, three'
```

How can I join a list of strings with `,` and create a string containing `one, two, three`?

System release is 740.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another way of writing `CONCATENATE LINES OF ...` is to use the 7.40 function [concat_lines_of( [table =] itab [sep = sep] )](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_740_index_htm/7.40/en-US/index.htm?file=abenconcatenation_functions.htm)

```
cl_demo_output=>display( concat_lines_of(
          table = value string_table( ( `one` ) ( `two` ) ( `three` ) )
          sep   = `, ` ) ).
```

(Result: 'one, two, three')

Comment: @Florian what do you mean with "ABAP command" in your comment?

Comment: `CONCATENATE LINES OF`

Answer (score 5):

I'm kind of spitballin' here but the following should work. 
You got a table of strings `lt_strings` and a variable for output `lv_concatenated`. ABAP has a built in command called concatenate and you can feed a table as input.

```
data: lt_strings type string_table,
      lv_concatenated type string.

concatenate lines of lt_strings into lv_concatenated separated by ','.
```

Comment: `CONCATENATE 'one' 'two' 'three' INTO DATA(lv_result) separated by ','.` should work on 7.3 and above.

Comment: Not 7.3: [inline declarations are available from **7.4**](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_740_index_htm/7.40/en-US/index.htm?file=abennews-740-expressions.htm)

Comment: CONCATENATE LINES OF is equivalent to the 7.40 function [`concat_lines_of( [table =] itab [sep = sep] )`](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_740_index_htm/7.40/en-US/index.htm?file=abenconcatenation_functions.htm)

Comment: @SandraRossi why not write your solution as answer? Then I can upvote it. Commenting is easier, too. Nevertheless thank you very much for pointing me to the new and nice abap features.